# Populate select option tag with dynamic data from xml link

Tags: javascript, json, dynamic, drop-down-menu, html-select

I need to populate select option tags with dynamic data that I get from an xml link.

Hello, I am working with sharepoint and I need to get a solution for my problem.
I have an empty select tag and I need to fill it with dynamic data from an xml link. 
https://scontent.ftun3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/66477621_1241321552715420_782504330790961152_n.png?_nc_cat=103&_nc_oc=AQlt1rE9uaqZ1xQ5hiMymOPlFsedDuxcpBPMP9C_RTgYJ6s8P5ekStaUIaC5MTiZyOY&_nc_ht=scontent.ftun3-1.fna&oh=bbda50d7782545a433025406a28b2396&oe=5DBECD7B

The data in the picture is statically typed and the name of the column in the xml link is `<d:ProjectOwnerName>`, but I want it to be dynamic. 
starting from this code, how can I do this?

```
$.ajax({url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/ProjectData/[en-US]/Projects",                           
                                        method: "GET",
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        headers: {Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"},       
                                        success: function(data) {     
                                        var dataResults = data.d.results;

               var listItemInfo ="";
                $.each(dataResults, function(key, value) 
                {
```

And this the html part:

```
<select style="color:black; font-weight:bold;" id="mylist" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option></option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Is your data `xml` or `json`?

Comment: @AlexKudryashev https://scontent.ftun3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/66817316_552301148638753_8143799129030524928_n.png?_nc_cat=110&_nc_eui2=AeE-buSNjyf-kN7yXT23PHYCu7QHd-vnRVEbtaOC4K3CeaIuomLVb0x7YflnAfHXOtSOM9odptImziiYbyscJWyo56xUpcWuNLTcdzPpTDPThA&_nc_oc=AQk8NaDID4Ba9IQLoKoohGtXAV_MTlZH-tJORblxWef6SQdnTAD_G92oyZOAskbFf-Y&_nc_ht=scontent.ftun3-1.fna&oh=930901b607c6d48ac26ff4159593537a&oe=5DB32AD3
This is a screenshot for my xml link that I must get my data from.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is `xml` then use `dataType:'xml'`. It may be something like this.

```
$.ajax({url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/ProjectData/[en-US]/Projects",                           
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "xml",//or json if xml is wrapped in json
    //headers: {Accept: "text/xml"},//make sure you need this       
    success: function(data) { 
        //check which is your desired XML
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.d);
        console.log(data.d.results);

        //suppose it is data.d.results
        var dataResults = data.d.results;
        var list = $('#mylist');
        $(dataResults).find('d\\:ProjectOwnerName')//this is how access namespaced property
          .each(function(){
            list.append($('<option />').text(this.innerText));
          });//each
       }//success
});//$.ajax
```